# XAML MVVM: How to make items visilibity grey out based on a bool condition from view model

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, visibility

I'm new for XAML and MVVM. I need to add a control to freeze/greyed out to disable user to click/select buttons/combobox once the device is connected successfully. For below, i need to freeze the combo selection COMPort once connection already been made. I also bind visibiloity once RS485 port type selected. Many thanks in advance :)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HP1cl.png)

Here is my code for XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Ports}" Visibility="{Binding RS485, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Name="portIdCombo" SelectedItem="{Binding COMPort}" />
```

Comment: IsEnabled = False ?

Comment: Hi Aybe, thanks! Problem solved by using IsEnabled = {Binding Bool}

Comment: Well done :DDDD